# How to move the user cache directory [~/.cache] out of the /home directory to another partition

Tags: google-chrome, environment-variables, cache

The .cache directory is full of volatile, non-essential files.

I would like to move it to a more appropriate partition, *i.e.* faster and not backed up.

I believe that ~/.pam_environment file is appropriate for this but am not sure if is the best or if it is documented properly or working properly.

Comment: How are you preserving /some/other/place/.cache between reboots? If one moves .cache to, say, /dev/shm, when the box is rebooted /dev/shm/.cache is missing and so ~/.cache is dangling symlink.

Comment: Related guide for google chrome here: https://www.joeyconway.com/blog/2011/09/11/ubuntu-ssd-move-chrome-cache-to-ram/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't care about keeping the stuff there across reboots, you can use tmpfs to store the cache.

Set something like the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /home/someuser/.cache tmpfs defaults,size=512M 0 0
```

Now, your .cache will be stored in memory instead of on disk, though if you have insufficient memory it could end up being swapped out.

A more traditional approach would be to move the directory to wherever you like and symlink it as appropriate:

```
mv ~/.cache /some/other/place
ln -s /some/other/place/.cache ~/
```

Comment: This is working well.  I had hoped to use pam-env as it is the "preffered" way, but this works, and if it isn't broke, don't fix it.  BTW Chrome is much speedier now!

Comment: `~/.pam_environment` is for setting environment variables, which has nothing to do with the task at hand. Besides, though some claim that `.pam_environment` is preferred, I don't think that's necessarily so, considering how few people (according to Google) are using it. `.bashrc` is good enough for me.

Comment: I think second option have one error, second line should be `ln -s /some/other/place/.cache ~/.cache`, not just link to ~/, how apps will know home is cache folder, not old .cache inside home?

Comment: If no filename is specified, then ln will use the original one. So, while your example will also work, there's no mistake in my answer.

Comment: how to verify if the fstab line really works as it should?

Comment: After mounting everything (`mount -a` or reboot) type `mount` by itself without any arguments. You'll get a list of everything that's currently mounted. Look through the list to verify if everything is as expected.