# Change kio cache directory

Tags: disk-usage, cache

I was wondering if there's a way to change the location of the cache directory used by `kio`. Currently when I go through my GoPro videos, they cache to `~/.cache/kioexec/krun/` which is on my SSD.

Given the size and frequency of these videos, I can see this putting some stress on the lifespan of my SSD, and would rather relocate this to the HDD. Would this be doable?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: And do the answers in [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/87314/248158) help?